# Replacing ADO.NET with Entity Framework. Is Entity Framework suitable for following scenario?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, sql-server-2008-r2, .net-4.5

**Question 1:** Should we use Entity Framework in a multi-user environment to implement a functionality which performs multiple updates (100 rows) on a table?

**Question 2:** Are we taking a right decision to use EF in following scenario?

**Scenario:** Stock Count webpage contains a editable gridview control which allows users to update 100 rows at a time.

**Background:** Stock Count is used to record stock quantities at period closure. The period closure for all organisation happens on Monday. There are around 10 live organisation and on average each organisation has at least 100+ site which does the stock closure on Monday at same time.

A similar screen which is based on ADO.NET is working fine. However the team is trying to introduce Entity Framework on the new screen. We did method level stress test and didn't got promising results for EF. We ran the tests for 2 minutes and simulated a user load from 5 users to 35 users.

**Here are the results:**

**ADO.NET** uses a stored procedure to make one database update at a time.

```
5 Users - Number of test per second per user - 80
35 Users - Number of test per second per user - 150
```

**EF** uses SaveChanges() method, which internally make one database update at a time.

```
5 Users - Number of test per second per user - 43
35 Users  - Number of test per second per user - 43
```

**EF code:**

#### Approach 1

```
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
context.Set<LocationData>().AddRange(data); //data is a collection of LocationData
foreach (var locationData in data)
{
    var entry = context.Entry(locationData);
    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

### Code profiler details for approach 1

[image]

#### Approach 2

```
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
foreach (var locationData in data)
{
    context.Set<LocationData>().Attach(data); 
    var entry = context.Entry(locationData);
    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

### Code profiler details for approach 2

[image]

### SQL Query generated by Entity Framework

```
exec sp_executesql N'
UPDATE [dbo].[LocationData]
SET [LocationId] = @0, [ClientId] = @1, [ProductId] = @2, 
[SupplierProductId] = @3, [MenuId] = @4, [MenuNumber] = @5, [CaskNumber] = @6
WHERE ([Id] = @7)',N'@0 bigint,@1 bigint,@2 bigint,@3 bigint,@4 bigint, @5 bigint,@6 nvarchar(64),@7 bigint',
@0=22371851,@1=22371851,@2=22371851,@3=22371851,@4=22371851,@5=22371851,@6=N'Cask0091',@7=22371851
```

### SQL Query generated by ADO.NET

```
Update LocationData
set 
 LocationId = @LocationId, 
 ClientId= @ClientID,  
 ProductId= @ProductId, 
 SupplierProductId=@SupplierProductId,  MenuId= @MenuId, 
 MenuNumber= @MenuNumber, 
 CaskNumber= @CaskNumber
WHERE   LocationData.Id = @Id
```

***These test were not executed under a transaction.***

I have used following for the development: Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, Sql Server R2, Entity Framework 6.0.2, .NET 4.5,C#

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  Entity Framework simplifies large model architecture, and it auto-generates SQL to do the hard "complex" bits.  If you're using EF for a simple read/write utility-type purpose you are better off with ADO.NET.  If you're looking to standardize and simplify the way a group of developers use your SQL Server, you should use entity framework.

Comment: I understand the purpose of EF and the features it provides. I am using it on a high traffic site where multiple users will be updating or inserting data. However I don't under what you mean by saying EF is not suitable for simple read/write operations. If data is added or updated, the system will end up doing doing either inserts or updates. Irrespective of what technology you use the database updates will happen by simple Inserts or Updates.

Comment: Not necessarily, there is a stored procedure that will allow you to see the last ran queries on a table.  Run your tests again and inspect the SQL.  You'll notice that EF will add a lot more "fluff" to the sql statement.  This is by design as they have to write the sql in a way that will work on most SQL servers.

Comment: I have included the SQL generated by EF in the question

Comment: Ahh, sp_executesql is your bottleneck.  It slows down performance.  There is likely a OPTION you can add to the query to speed it up, though I wouldn't know how to do that in EF.  Even though sp_executesql may take longer to execute, however it may be more efficient given some of the articles I've read.  To answer your question EF is just a framework to help standardize the usage of SQL and to be extended in many cases such as OData.  If you really need the speed there are other frameworks out there that extend ADO.NET directly.  XPO for one.

Comment: Does that mean EF is not suitable for high traffic site?

Comment: It can be, with some tweaks.  But out of the box, i would say no.

Comment: I have switched off change tracking, using pre-compiled views. However I can say the EF is not optimised enough to handle multiple update statement in a medium/high traffic site..